# java linux server: class not found exception though jar in classpath

Tags: java, json, linux

Im running a Java application on an Amazon EC2 instance which is a linux server. I included a json jar in the build path and I checked the class path and it's there. When I import the class

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

I dont get any compilation errors, but when I execute my app I get the ClassNotFoundException.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
at Group.run(Group.java:62)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?
I have tried to fix this for weeks now, I'm really frustrated!

Comment: Show `java ...` command you use to launch application.

Comment: from bin directory: 

    `java Server`

classpath:

    `...`
    `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/java-json.jar" />`
    `...`

Comment: Build path for a tool can be different from a CLASSPATH. You need to use -classpath or -cp option when you run the app to provide the correct CLASSPATH, or setup an env variable - CLASSPATH

Comment: can you give me an example using -CLASSPATH ?

Comment: Do you run your app on a server or standalone? What server? Did you configure it in Eclipse? You really need to provide more info to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I run it on an instance of EC2 server, but never mind that, it works! I used

    `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/ec2-user/server/lib/java-json.jar` and now it runs! Thank a lot! can you please briefly explain why does it work now and didn't work earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be the environment setting problem.

Try to edit `~/.bash_profile` and append the `CLASSPATH` value like:

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/your/jar/folder/
export CLASSPATH
```

Then using following cmd to make the setting work:

`source ~/.bash_profile`